# Lightning Scheduler for the external web page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, servicecloud, sales

We have enabled lightning scheduler in our org and we need to add the scheduling app in our external website.

I have setup all the things given [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=ls_set_up_inbound.htm&type=5), but still I can't see anything in my external website.

I guess, I'm confused with external page for an inbound scheduling flow (Which I created in salesforce) and Inbound Scheduling Flow (Which is in my external site).

But not sure what I missed. If would be great if anyone help me on this.

Comment: did you get any work around?. have you implemented this functionality successfully.?

Comment: No and salesforce support is very slow on this

Comment: Hi, were you able to make any progress?

Comment: No, still looking for solutions

Comment: Are you able to fix this ? Urgent.